# User agent from Azure Sign-ins via MS Graph (PowerShell)

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am retrieving user sign-ins from Azure using MS Graph (PowerShell)
Almost all the information I need I can get except "User Agent" that I can see via web.
Is there any way to get that information?
The command I am using is Get-MgAuditLogSignIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserAgent doesn't exist on the default 1.0 Graph endpoint, but it does on the beta endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/graph/api/resources/signin?view=graph-rest-beta

So after using `Connect-MgGraph`, enter `Select-MgProfile -Name beta` and try your `Get-MgAuditLogSignIn` again; you should have a UserAgent property.

Comment: Wow! Who could know this exists and could be processed as simple as this approach :) 
Thank you very much!

Comment: I presume it worked? If so, could you please mark it as answered?  :-)

Comment: Found another interesting issue....
I am going to share it with the team on github, bout also worth asking here:



Each time I run this 

$signIns = Get-MgAuditLogSignIn -All -Filter "CreatedDateTime gt $($yesterdayDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")) and CreatedDateTime lt $($yesterdayDate.AddHours(24).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")) and ClientAppUsed ne 'Browser' and ClientAppUsed ne 'Mobile Apps and Desktop clients' and ClientAppUsed ne ''"  

It produces different records number. Three times - three results of 4k/12k/14k records.
Is there are any limits for downloading data?

Comment: I see you turned this into it's own question already.  :-)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71578194/get-mgauditlogsignin-all-different-outputs-each-time-i-run-the-command