# Get-MgAuditLogSignIn -All - different outputs each time I run the command

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am using MgGraph with the beta profile.
Each time I run my script (it should grab all the sign-ins from the previous day) I get a different number of records - 14k, 12k, 7k...
The same request, the same filters, just run the same script once again and once again.
Is there any limit for requests (like once in a day or in an hour or something else)?
This is how I am downloading:

```
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId XYZ -TenantId ABC -Certificate $cert
Select-MgProfile -Name beta

#Create a yesterday date
#Note - this is UTC
$yesterdayDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).AddHours(-(Get-Date).Hour).AddMinutes(-(Get-Date).Minute).AddSeconds(-(Get-Date).Second).AddMilliseconds(-(Get-Date).Milliseconds)

Write-Host
Write-Host "Downloading data... Start time:" $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")

$signIns = Get-MgAuditLogSignIn -All -Filter "CreatedDateTime gt $($yesterdayDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")) and CreatedDateTime lt $($yesterdayDate.AddHours(24).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ")) and ClientAppUsed ne 'Browser' and ClientAppUsed ne 'Mobile Apps and Desktop clients' and ClientAppUsed ne ''"

Write-Host "Done downloading data... End time:" $(Get-Date -Format "hh:mm:ss")
```

The same result, actually, I am getting using the v1.0 graph.

Comment: The Microsoft.Graph PowerShell module is just a wrapper around the underlying Graph API.  When I have questions like this, I refer to the [Graph API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). Having said that, I don't see anything that would explain what you're seeing.  I just tried that myself, and got exactly 76 records 4 times in a row.  Are you re-running the whole script each time?  It'll change the time span slightly each time; maybe that accounts for the difference?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I ran the commands individually, and then ran the `$signIns = ...` line followed by `$signIns.Count` four times; I didn't run the entire script.  If you keep `$yesterdayDate` unchanged, does `Get-MgAuditLogSignIn` return the same number each time?

Comment: It seems like my query is veeery looong and causes timeouts. I have noticed that despite I am asking to provide me a 24h report, I get only a couple of hours. WIll try to split the report by 1 hour or 30 minutes.